# Is that possible to call to external PHP script from Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to call to external PHP script using Ajax like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({'url': 'http://stokes.chop.edu/web/zscore/result.php',
            'type': 'POST',
            'success': function(response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                alert('[' + response + ']');
            },
            'error': function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error');
            }
    });
});
```

The result is: `[]` (i.e. `success` function is called!),
but I see the following error in HTTPFOX plugin for FireFox:

**Error loading content (NS_ERROR_DOCUMENT_NOT_CACHED)**

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: It looks like a HTTPFox bug: http://code.google.com/p/httpfox/issues/detail?id=20

Comment: Lol, this would be such a gaping security hole if browsers allowed cross domain requests like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot load contents from pages that does not have the same domain name as the one from which the ajax request is called from. This is a well known security feature call the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: There are special mechanisms, such as [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), but they require server support.